# how to share a list item template across several AngularJS views?

Tags: html, angularjs, list, templates, reusability

In my single-page app with AngularJS (1.5) I need to present a list of items on various views.

However the items in the list are not always the same (for instance, it could be the full list on page A with say 100 objects, and a filtered list for items having a given property on page B, with say 10 objects, and same idea for pages C, D, ...).

I would like to make sure the presentation is always the same across pages (i.e. 3 lines per item, an icon on the left, and a badge on the right), and avoid HTML code duplication.

In addition to the list, each page has some specific content which differ betweeen page A, B, C, ..., so I would like to be able to embed some kind of "list component".

A first idea would be to have a "listItem.html" template that I could include in the views of page A and page B, but I can't find how, since the array of objects is not the same depending on the page - and it has to be given in the ng-repeat.

I have also thought to have a "MyList.js" controller and a "mylist.html" view template to manage this list within the views for page A and page B, but I would need to pass them a different array of objects, so I am not sure it is feasible.

So finally I have no working solution.

Would you have any suggestion for that? Many thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could address my requirement by developing a directive, which takes the list of objects as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a service which holds the items that you have and a method for filtering the list:(note this answer is very general to give you idea, not a working example!)

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('listService', function() {
        return {
            getAllItems: getAllItems
        }

        function getAllItems(query) {
            if(!query) {
                return list;
            } 
            return list.filter()
        }
    })
```

you define a state like this

```
  var state = {
        url: 'list/:query',
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: ListController
    }
```

and in your controller you inject the listService like like this:

```
   angular.mdoule('app')
        .controller('ListController', function(listServide)) {
            .
            .
            .
        }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I did not mention that on pages A, B, ..., there are other specific contents, in addition to the list, and which differ from page to page. The list is only one compenent of the pages. In this case, I believe what you propose does not work unfornately. I will edit my question to add what I forgot. Thanks again